# PC speaker 3.5 mm stereo jack to XLR on Zoom H4n Pro

Tags: zoom-h4n, xlr, pc

I have a [Zoom H4n Pro](https://zoomcorp.com/en/gb/handheld-recorders/handheld-recorders/h4n-pro/h4n-pro-support/) and I am trying to connect my PC 3.5 speaker plug to the H4n Pro's XLR connections.
I want to do this because I want to record voice calls. I need to use the XLR and not the Ext Mic connection because using the Ext Mic disables the voice microphones on the device and I need to use them to record my side of the conversation.

Now, to connect the PC 3.5 speaker plug to the XLR I am using these two connectors:

- [3.5 male jack to XLR male](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07G8DKPYZ?ref=ppx_pop_mob_ap_share)
  [image]
- [XLR female jack to two XLR male](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07H7QS8KQ?ref=ppx_pop_mob_ap_share)
  [image]

The sound passes through and gets recorded but with it there is a huge humming sound. I suspect the XLR is expecting an unpowered source and the PC plug is probably powered but I have no idea if this is the case or if it could be resolved by reconfiguring the H4n Pro.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but this is wired about as wrong as it's possible to do:\

You're running stereo into balanced line, then splitting the balanced line & hoping to get stereo back. That is not going to happen.
Also you're trying to run a line-level output into a mic-level input. That's going to burn something out if you're not careful.

This is the pinout for the H4n [I already inlined the pinouts for your two cables into your question, so you can see just how this is never going to work.]

[image]

All you need to do this is one cable, TRS stereo to two TR mono [this will just run unbalanced without any further futzing].

[image]

Info from https://zoomcorp.com/media/documents/E_H4n_Pro_QuickGuide.pdf

Some background reading on how balanced line works - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_audio

Comment: Thank you @Tetsujin. For the reply and for the reading tip. I suppose you are talking about a cable like this: https://www.amazon.fr/syst%C3%A8me-domestique-ordinateur-portable-amplificateur/dp/B08RHXYHNQ/. But how would I then plug that to the XLR connectors? I was looking for a couple of TS female mono to XLR addapter but I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: Forget my last comment... I just realized that the XLR female connectors also take the 6,5mm jacks in the middel hole.

Comment: You don't want XLRs at all & I'm not sure why you still think you do, even after my answer.. Those sockets take **either** XLR or standard jack; one is mic level, the other is line level. You want line level, so you want jacks. Running line level into mic inputs is "not good".

Comment: It was mostly ignorance of my part... :-) I already cleared that in my previous comment. Thanks a lot.